# How to Use Linq Projection with IMongoQueryable<TEntity> in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using C# 8, .net standard 2.0 with MongoDB.Driver v2.9.2. I'm migrating a project from RavenDB to MongoDB.

I need to use **include** somehow with IMongoQueryable in my GetAllAsync method but I confused. Here is the method;

```
public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy, 
                               bool isDescendingOrder = false, 
                               Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> projection = null,
                               CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            IMongoQueryable<TEntity> mongoQueryable = Collection.AsQueryable();

            if (isDescendingOrder)
            {
                return await mongoQueryable.OrderByDescending(orderBy)
                                           .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }

            return await mongoQueryable.OrderBy(orderBy)
                                       .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

What I tried so far; I can build same query with "Find()" method but
SortByDescending method needs "`Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderBy`" - can't work with `Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy` like upper code block that I provided.

```
Builders<TEntity>.Sort.Ascending(orderBy).

Func<TEntity, TOrderBy> compile = orderBy.Compile();
Collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project(projection).SortByDescending(compile).ToListAsync();
```

And the last thing, here is how I solved this in RavenDB:

```
public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy, 
                                       bool isDescendingOrder = false, 
                                       Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> projection = null,
                                       CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            ICollection<TEntity> entities;

            IRavenQueryable<TEntity> query = AsyncDocumentSession.Query<TEntity>();

            if (projection != null)
            {
                query = query.Include(projection);
            }

            if (isDescendingOrder)
            {
                entities = await query.OrderByDescending(orderBy)
                                      .ToListAsync(token: cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                entities = await query.OrderBy(orderBy)
                                      .ToListAsync(token: cancellationToken);
            }

            return entities;
        }
```

Comment: Could you show sample usage of your method ? Is `projection` supposed to represent single field like `x => x.MyField` that's going to be returned as output or you would like to specify more than that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the following a try:

```cs
        public static async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TEntity, TOrderBy>
            (
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy,
            bool isDescendingOrder = false,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> projection = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
            )
        {
            var query = _collection.AsQueryable();

            var sortedQuery = isDescendingOrder ?
                                query.OrderByDescending(orderBy) :
                                query.OrderBy(orderBy);

            query = projection != null ?
                        sortedQuery.Select(projection) :
                        sortedQuery.Select(x=> x);

            return await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken) as ICollection<TEntity>;
        }
```

test program:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Person : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public async static Task Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            await (new Person { Name = "Person", Age = 22 }).SaveAsync();

            var result =
                await GetAllAsync<Person, object>(
                    p => p.Age,
                    true,
                    p => new Person { Name = p.Name, Age = p.Age });
        }

        public static async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TEntity, TOrderBy>
            (
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy,
            bool isDescendingOrder = false,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> projection = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
            ) 
        {
            var query = DB.Queryable<TEntity>();

            var sortedQuery = isDescendingOrder ?
                                query.OrderByDescending(orderBy) :
                                query.OrderBy(orderBy);

            query = projection != null ?
                        sortedQuery.Select(projection) :
                        sortedQuery.Select(x=> x);

            return await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken) as ICollection<TEntity>;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I upvoted your answer but interface method has `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> projection = null` for projection, so it's not `Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> projection = null` . Do you have any reason to use "TEntity" not "object" ? Is it supposed to be TEntity ?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. It's working with `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> projection = null` too, don't need TEntity, TEntity. But what is supposed to be? I mean, what is the best practice for it ? Using "object" or using "TEntity" as second type of Expression function ?

Comment: @Lost_In_Library use `TEntity` if you want the output type of the projection to be the same as the input type. or use `object` as the return type to be able to project into any kind of type. such as `x => new { Prop = x.Prop }` or `x => new SomeType { Prop = x.Prop }`.

Comment: @Lost_In_Library the reason i set it to `TEntity` is because the return type of your function is `ICollection<TEntity>` which means you won't be projecting to any other type than `TEntity`.